# Is it permissible to benefit from an action on shabbos by someone who follows a valid but more lenient ruling?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, stringency-chumrah, leniencies

If there is an action which not all poskim agree is melocho and one person holds by the more lenient opinion is it permissible to benefit from that action or ask them to preform it?

For example if one did not use the eruv in a certain area could you ask someone who does to carry an object or push your stroller for you?